# Is there a way to pull back the field name after aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm using elastic search 1.5.2 and was wondering if there is a way to add the field name to the return of an aggregation other than the name of the aggregation itself, so that `age` can stay age and not `Customer.Age`

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "age": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Customer.Age",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the return to look something like this

```
aggregations: {
    age: {
        doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0
        sum_other_doc_count: 0
        field: Customer.Age
        buckets: [6]
           0:  {
              key: "unknown"
              doc_count: 607103
           }            
    }
```

And what I currently get does not include field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment (before 2.0 is released). However, since the name of the aggregation can be essentially anything, you can encode both aggregation name and the field in the aggregation name and then parse it on the client side:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "age/Customer.Age": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Customer.Age",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In v2.0 it will be possible to specify arbitrary [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/agg-metadata.html) that will be returned back to the user:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "age: {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Customer.Age",
                "size": 10
            },
            "meta": {
                "field": "Customer.Age"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I figured. I was hoping there was some magic to get it to work differently.

Comment: Magic is coming, but not available in production yet. I have mentioned it my answer just in case somebody stumbles upon this in the future.